# How can I fix the error in mySQL, ERROR 1146 (42S02)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have created the product table but when I go I have to insert some type of data. I get a mistake as if the tree would not exist if it exits.

I would like to know why I get that kind of error, I do not know if I need to make a change in the configuration or I have some syntax error.

### code of Table

---

```
CREATE TABLE product (
p_code VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
p_descript VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
p_indate DATE NOT NULL,
p_qoh SMALLINT NOT NULL,
p_min SMALLINT NOT NULL,
p_price NUMERIC(8, 2) NOT NULL,
p_discount NUMERIC(5, 2) NOT NULL,
v_code INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (v_code) REFERENCES vendor(v_code) ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

---

This is the data I want to use

### ## Code ##

```
INSERT INTO product VALUES (
'11QER/ 31',' Power painter', 15 psi., 3- nozzle',
'03- Nov- 11', 8, 5, 109.99, 0.00, 25595);
```

---

This is the error

### ## ERROR ##

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mod07.proudct' doesn't exist
```

---

Comment: `proudct` in the error message? Is this correct?

Comment: @forpas Yes is this correct

Comment: So check your statements, somewhere you misspelled the `product` table with `proudct`.

Comment: @forpas Okay I go check right now and Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least a couple of problems:

- It seems that the second column (`p_descript`) does not have the correct format.
- Incorrect date value for column `p_indate`.

Try:

```sql
INSERT INTO `product`
VALUES (
   '11QER/ 31',
-- ' Power painter', 15 psi., 3- nozzle',
   ' Power painter\', 15 psi., 3- nozzle',
-- '03- Nov- 11',
   STR_TO_DATE('03- Nov- 11', '%d- %b- %y'),
   8,
   5,
   109.99,
   0.00,
   25595
);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a62e8c42c9fb20233cd566715f7c5d7).

Comment: Okay I go try, 
Thank you for you answer.